# не отправляются переменные формы

Tags: php, jquery

```
            <form id="request">
                <div class="one_third_100"><input type="text" id="name_req" placeholder="Ваше имя"/></div>
                <div class="one_third_100"><input type="text" id="phone_req" placeholder="Введите номер телефона"/></div>
                <div class="one_third_100"><div class="but_r"><input type="submit" value="Перезвонить мне"/></div></div>
            </form>


$('form#request').submit(function () {
    var name=$('input#name_req').val();
    var phone=$('input#phone_req').val();
    var error=0;
    if (name==''){
        $('input#name_req').css('border-color','red');
        error=1;
    }
    if (phone==''){
        $('input#phone_req').css('border-color','red');
        error=1;
    }
    if (error==0){
        $.post( "../mail/send.php",{ name: name, phone: phone }, function( data ) {
            $('div.but_r').html('<div class="good">Сообщение успешно отправлено!</div>');
        });
    }
    return false;
});


<?php
  /* получатели */
  $to= "mr.dvorezky@yandex.ru";
  $name=htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']);
  $phone=htmlspecialchars($_POST['phone']);
  $subject = "Запрос консультации";
 /* сообщение */
 $message = '
 <html>
 <body>
 <p><strong>Запрос с сайта:</strong></p>
 <strong>Имя:</strong>&nbsp;'.$name.'<br/>
 <strong>Телефон:</strong>&nbsp;'.$phone.'<br/>
 </body>
 </html>
 ';

 $headers= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
 $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";

 $headers .= "From: Luxstahl.com <info@luxstahl.com>\r\n";
 mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
 ?>
```

Comment: Для начала попробуйте вместо `{ name: name, phone: phone }` `{ "name": name, "phone": phone }`

Comment: Что значит "не отправляется"?

Comment: на почту приходит только $message, переменные $name и $phone пустые

Comment: Я проверил сам с кавычками и без, работают оба варианта. К сожалению, трудно сказать, что у вас идет не так, без взгляда на реальный пример. Попробуйте проверить в Инспекторе браузера, реально ли у вас отправляются данные, смотреть тут: https://yadi.sk/i/9T8tA0xR3HUDBA

Comment: в console: XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://luxstahl.com/mail/send.php. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://lux.loc' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Известная фишка, хотя странно, что у вас такое выдается - вы же делаете не кроссдоменной запрос, а с одного и того же домена. Первым делом проверьте адреса, которые у вас в строке браузера и в строке запроса (смотреть там же, в инспекторе, сравнить вплоть до http/https, www. и без www), ну и если все точно совпадает, решите проблему например как тут написано http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33820142/getting-request-doesnt-pass-access-control-check-no-access-control-allow-orig - добавив в htaccess `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"`

Comment: Ну или можете вместо `../mail/send.php` написать `https://luxstahl.com/mail/send.php` в коде js, тоже по идее может помочь. Скажите тогда, если какой-то из вариантов сработает, я оформлю это в виде ответа и вы сможете его принять.

Comment: по http работает, а по по https не работает, даже если прописать https://luxstahl.com/mail/send.php в коде js

Comment: пишет: main.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at main.js:1
(anonymous) @ main.js:1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прошу прощения, господа, что отвлек. Решение своего вопроса нашел сам после долгих исканий. Весь код написанный мной и поправленный вами работает: и мой, и ваши предложения. Я просто переходил с http на https и ссылки на jquery-библиотеку остались в http. После изменения на https протокол все работает. Спасибо!

Answer (score -1):

у формы по умолчанию метод отправки "get", сделайте

```
<form id="request" method="post">
```

либо на серверной стороне читайте переменные не из `$_POST`, а из `$_GET`.

Comment: Он не использует метод отправки формы, обратите внимание, что данные отправляются функцией `$.post()`, а в конце функции `submit` возвращается `false`, что отключает тот самый отправку формы в принципе, что методом `post`, что методом `get`.